# Create a variable in `df1` depending on one variable of `df1` (`df1$var1`) and one variable of `df2` that is changeable depending on `df1$var1`

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, lubridate

I have data frame `df1` that summarises fish depths over time. `df1$Site` tells you the site where the fish was, `df1$Ind` tells you the individual and `df1$Depth` tells you the depth where the fish was at a specific `df1$Datetime`.

On the other hand, I have `df2` that summarises the intensity of the currents over time (EVERY THREE HOURS) from the surface to 39 meters depth at intervals of 8 meters (`m0-7`, `m8-15`, `m16-23`, `m24-31` and `m32-39`). As an example:

```
df1<-data.frame(Datetime=c("2016-08-01 15:34:07","2016-08-01 16:25:16","2016-08-01 17:29:16","2016-08-01 18:33:16","2016-08-01 20:54:16","2016-08-01 22:48:16"),Site=c("BD","HG","BD","BD","BD","BD"),Ind=c(16,17,19,16,17,16), Depth=c(5.3,24,36.4,42,NA,22.1))
df1$Datetime<-as.POSIXct(df1$Datetime, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",tz="UTC")


> df1
             Datetime Site Ind Depth
1 2016-08-01 15:34:07   BD  16   5.3
2 2016-08-01 16:25:16   HG  17  24.0
3 2016-08-01 17:29:16   BD  19  36.4
4 2016-08-01 18:33:16   BD  16  42.0
5 2016-08-01 20:54:16   BD  17    NA
6 2016-08-01 22:48:16   BD  16  22.1

df2<-data.frame(Datetime=c("2016-08-01 12:00:00","2016-08-01 15:00:00","2016-08-01 18:00:00","2016-08-01 21:00:00","2016-08-02 00:00:00"), Site=c("BD","BD","BD","BD","BD"),var1=c(2.75,4,6.75,2.25,4.3),var2=c(3,4,4.75,3,2.1),var3=c(2.75,4,5.75,2.25,1.4),var4=c(3.25,3,6.5,2.75,3.4),var5=c(3,4,4.75,3,1.7))
df2$Datetime<-as.POSIXct(df2$Datetime, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",tz="UTC")
colnames(df2)<-c("Datetime","Site","m0-7","m8-15","m16-23","m24-31","m32-39")

> df2
             Datetime Site m0-7 m8-15 m16-23 m24-31 m32-39
1 2016-08-01 12:00:00   BD 2.75  3.00   2.75   3.25   3.00
2 2016-08-01 15:00:00   BD 4.00  4.00   4.00   3.00   4.00
3 2016-08-01 18:00:00   BD 6.75  4.75   5.75   6.50   4.75
4 2016-08-01 21:00:00   BD 2.25  3.00   2.25   2.75   3.00
5 2016-08-02 00:00:00   BD 4.30  2.10   1.40   3.40   1.70
```

I want to create a new column in `df1` called `df1$Current.Int` that summarises the current intensity at the depth when and where the fish was according to what `df2` says about currents.

I would like to get this:

```
> df1
             Datetime Site Ind Depth Current.Int
1 2016-08-01 15:34:07   BD  16   5.3        4.00
2 2016-08-01 16:25:16   HG  17  24.0          NA # Currents of this site are not included in df2
3 2016-08-01 17:29:16   BD  19  36.4        4.75
4 2016-08-01 18:33:16   BD  16  42.0        4.75
5 2016-08-01 20:54:16   BD  17    NA          NA
6 2016-08-01 22:48:16   BD  16  22.1        1.40
```

Just to point out that since the current records are every three hours, every hour indicated in `df2$Datetime` represents one hour and a half more, and one hour and a half less. That is, the current intensity pointed out in `df2` at `21:00:00` reflects the currents between `19:30:00` and `22:30:00`. The same with the rest of the hours.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: You would need to use some conditional / unequal join. This blog article will help: https://www.r-bloggers.com/in-between-a-rock-and-a-conditional-join/amp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dates didn't match so they are changed for the example. With this approach, you can check exactly how the match has worked and ensure it is as you want it.

```
df1<-data.frame(Datetime=c("2016-08-18 15:34:07","2016-08-18 16:25:16","2016-08-18 17:29:16","2016-08-18 18:33:16","2016-08-18 20:54:16","2016-08-18 22:48:16"),Site=c("BD","HG","BD","BD","BD","BD"),Ind=c(16,17,19,16,17,16), Depth=c(5.3,24,36.4,42,NA,22.1))
df1$Datetime<-as.POSIXct(df1$Datetime, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",tz="UTC")

df2<-data.frame(Datetime=c("2016-08-18 12:00:00","2016-08-18 15:00:00","2016-08-18 18:00:00","2016-08-18 21:00:00","2016-08-19 00:00:00"), Site=c("BD","BD","BD","BD","BD"),var1=c(2.75,4,6.75,2.25,4.3),var2=c(3,4,4.75,3,2.1),var3=c(2.75,4,5.75,2.25,1.4),var4=c(3.25,3,6.5,2.75,3.4),var5=c(3,4,4.75,3,1.7))
df2$Datetime<-as.POSIXct(df2$Datetime, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",tz="UTC")
colnames(df2)<-c("Datetime","Site","m0-7","m8-15","m16-23","m24-31","m32-39")

library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

# Round the date and convert the depth to match the look-up. 
df1 = df1 %>% 
  mutate(
    Datetime_rounded = round_date(Datetime, "3 hour"),
    Depth_ind = ifelse(Depth < 8, "m0-7", 
                  ifelse(Depth > 7 & Depth < 16, "m8-15", 
                    ifelse(Depth > 15 & Depth < 24, "m16-23",
                      ifelse(Depth > 23 & Depth < 32, "m24-31",
                        ifelse(Depth > 31 & Depth < 40, "m32-39", NA)
                      )
                    )
                  )
                )
  )

# Wide to long on the intensity columns. 
df2 = df2 %>% 
  tidyr::gather("Depth_ind", "Intensity", 3:7)

# Join
df1 %>% 
  left_join(df2, by = c("Datetime_rounded" = "Datetime", 
                        "Site",
                        "Depth_ind"))

             Datetime Site Ind Depth    Datetime_rounded Depth_ind Intensity
1 2016-08-18 15:34:07   BD  16   5.3 2016-08-18 15:00:00      m0-7      4.00
2 2016-08-18 16:25:16   HG  17  24.0 2016-08-18 15:00:00    m24-31        NA
3 2016-08-18 17:29:16   BD  19  36.4 2016-08-18 18:00:00    m32-39      4.75
4 2016-08-18 18:33:16   BD  16  42.0 2016-08-18 18:00:00      <NA>        NA
5 2016-08-18 20:54:16   BD  17    NA 2016-08-18 21:00:00      <NA>        NA
6 2016-08-18 22:48:16   BD  16  22.1 2016-08-19 00:00:00    m16-23      1.40

# EDIT ----
## As per the request, the width of the final depth range can be adjusted as you wish, e.g. to a max depth of 60 m.

# Round the date and convert the depth to match the look-up. 
df1 = df1 %>% 
  mutate(
    Datetime_rounded = round_date(Datetime, "3 hour"),
    Depth_ind = ifelse(Depth < 8, "m0-7", 
                  ifelse(Depth > 7 & Depth < 16, "m8-15", 
                    ifelse(Depth > 15 & Depth < 24, "m16-23",
                      ifelse(Depth > 23 & Depth < 32, "m24-31",
                        ifelse(Depth > 31 & Depth < 60, "m32-39", NA)
                      )
                    )
                  )
                )
  )
```

Comment: Hi Ewen!! Your code is almost perfect!!! I only have one question, in `df1[4, ]` you get in `Intensity` a `NA` because the depth is bigger than the deepest interval (32-39 meters). In those cases, when the fish is deeper than 39 meters, I want to assign it the intensity of the deepest layer, in this case for instance `4.75`. Do you know how to do it? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Thanks. Just change the range of   "m32-39" to whatever you wish, e.g. `ifelse(Depth > 31 & Depth < 60, "m32-39", NA)`

Answer (score 1):

This can be done directly in a single SQL statement.  We left join `df1` to `df2` with the indicated `on` condition grouping by the `df1` row.  Calculating `max(b.Datetime)` over the indicated group will pick out the appropriate row of `df2`.  (If `a.Datetime`, `a.Site` does not uniquely define a row of `df1` then group by `a.rowid` instead.) At the end we remove that column using `[-1]`.

We used the data shown in the Note at the end since the data in the question did not have corresponding dates in `df1` and `df2`.

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf("select max(b.Datetime), a.*,
  case when a.Depth <= 7 then b.[m0-7]
       when a.Depth <= 15 then b.[m8-15]
       when a.Depth <= 23 then b.[m16-23]
       when a.Depth <= 31 then b.[m24-31]
       else b.[m32-39]
  end as [Current.Int]
  from df1 a
  left join df2 b on a.Site = b.Site and a.Datetime >= b.Datetime
  group by a.Datetime, a.Site")[-1]
```

giving:

```
             Datetime Site Ind Depth Current.Int
1 2016-08-01 15:34:07   BD  16   5.3        4.00
2 2016-08-01 16:25:16   HG  17  24.0          NA
3 2016-08-01 17:29:16   BD  19  36.4        4.00
4 2016-08-01 18:33:16   BD  16  42.0        4.75
5 2016-08-01 20:54:16   BD  17    NA        4.75
6 2016-08-01 22:48:16   BD  16  22.1        2.25
```

### Note

This is the input used and is the same as in the question except:

1. the UTC time zone has been eliminated. If you want to keep the UTC time zone change your session time zone to UTC using `Sys.setenv(TZ='UTC')`. Another possibility to deal with timezones is to use character strings rather than POSIXct for the `Datetime` columns in which case you can't have time zone problems in the first place.
2. the last line was added to improve the example since the dates did not match.

Here is the input used.

```
df1<-data.frame(Datetime=c("2016-08-01 15:34:07","2016-08-01 16:25:16","2016-08-01 17:29:16","2016-08-01 18:33:16","2016-08-01 20:54:16","2016-08-01 22:48:16"),Site=c("BD","HG","BD","BD","BD","BD"),Ind=c(16,17,19,16,17,16), Depth=c(5.3,24,36.4,42,NA,22.1))
df1$Datetime<-as.POSIXct(df1$Datetime, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

df2<-data.frame(Datetime=c("2016-08-18 12:00:00","2016-08-18 15:00:00","2016-08-18 18:00:00","2016-08-18 21:00:00","2016-08-19 00:00:00"), Site=c("BD","BD","BD","BD","BD"),var1=c(2.75,4,6.75,2.25,4.3),var2=c(3,4,4.75,3,2.1),var3=c(2.75,4,5.75,2.25,1.4),var4=c(3.25,3,6.5,2.75,3.4),var5=c(3,4,4.75,3,1.7))
df2$Datetime<-as.POSIXct(df2$Datetime, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
colnames(df2)<-c("Datetime","Site","m0-7","m8-15","m16-23","m24-31","m32-39")

df2$Datetime <- as.POSIXct(paste("2016-08-01", sub(".* ", "", df2$Datetime)))
```

Comment: Thanks G. Grothendieck! You were right! I changed the dates in `df2` since they didn't match with times in `df1`. I don't really understand your output after running your code. Your output changed the `Datetime`. For instance, the first row should contain the time `15:34:07`. I guess that the values of `Current.Int` don't match with what I expect because of that... 

Just an extra comment: I need to use the currents info from `df2` that is closest to the `Datetime` in `df1`. For instance, for the time `16:25:16` in `df1` the appropriate `Datetime` of `df2` is `15:00:00`.

Comment: Another example, for the time `2016-08-01 22:48:16` in `df1` the closest `Datetime` of `df2` is `2016-08-02 00:00:00`. Do you know how to solve these problems? Thanks in advance for your time :)

Comment: This was a time zone problem.  I have now removed the tz= in the input shown in the Note to avoid that.  You can alternately set your session's time zone to UTC or define the Datetime columns as character strings.

Answer (score 0):

As long as your data isn't huge, you may not have to embark down the path of conditional joins.  Instead, join based only using Site first and then filter out the extra observations afterwards.  It's not particularly efficient, but it might be easier than turning to `sqldf`.

Note I made a few changes to the data you supplied so that the dates would match up.

```
library(tidyverse)  

df1<-data.frame(Datetime=c("2016-08-01 15:34:07","2016-08-01 16:25:16","2016-08-01 17:29:16","2016-08-01 18:33:16","2016-08-01 20:54:16","2016-08-01 22:48:16"),
                Site=c("BD","HG","BD","BD","BD","BD"),
                Ind=c(16,17,19,16,17,16), 
                Depth=c(5.3,24,36.4,42,NA,22.1),
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df1$Datetime<-as.POSIXct(df1$Datetime, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",tz="UTC")

df2<-data.frame(Datetime=c("2016-08-01 12:00:00","2016-08-01 15:00:00","2016-08-01 18:00:00","2016-08-01 21:00:00","2016-08-02 00:00:00"), 
                Site=c("BD","BD","BD","BD","BD"),
                var1=c(2.75,4,6.75,2.25,4.3),
                var2=c(3,4,4.75,3,2.1),
                var3=c(2.75,4,5.75,2.25,1.4),
                var4=c(3.25,3,6.5,2.75,3.4),
                var5=c(3,4,4.75,3,1.7),
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df2$Datetime<-as.POSIXct(df2$Datetime, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",tz="UTC")
colnames(df2)<-c("Datetime_CI","Site","m0-7","m8-15","m16-23","m24-31","m32-39")



#Tidy the data in df2 so that that we have two columns for min and max Depth
#and a single column for the value of the current intensity
df2 <- df2 %>% 
  gather(-Datetime_CI, -Site, key = Depth, value = Current.Int) %>% 
  separate(Depth, c("minDepth", "maxDepth")) %>% 
  mutate(minDepth = as.numeric(str_sub(minDepth, 2, nchar(minDepth))))

#join df1 and df2 based on the Site alone
df1 %>% 
  inner_join(df2, by = "Site") %>% 
  #now filter out any observations where depth is not between the min and max
  filter(Depth >= minDepth,
         Depth <= maxDepth,
         #now exclude any current intensity observations prior to Datetime
         Datetime > Datetime_CI) %>% 
  #finally, take the first current intensity observation after Datetime
  group_by(Datetime, Site, Ind, Depth) %>% 
  filter(Datetime_CI == max(Datetime_CI))


# A tibble: 6 x 8
# Groups:   Datetime, Site, Ind, Depth [4]
Datetime            Site    Ind Depth Datetime_CI         minDepth maxDepth Current.Int
<dttm>              <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dttm>                 <dbl> <chr>          <dbl>
1 2016-08-01 15:34:07 BD       16   5.3 2016-08-01 15:00:00        0 7               4   
2 2016-08-01 17:29:16 BD       19  36.4 2016-08-01 15:00:00        0 7               4   
3 2016-08-01 17:29:16 BD       19  36.4 2016-08-01 15:00:00       32 39              4   
4 2016-08-01 18:33:16 BD       16  42   2016-08-01 18:00:00        0 7               6.75
5 2016-08-01 22:48:16 BD       16  22.1 2016-08-01 21:00:00        0 7               2.25
6 2016-08-01 22:48:16 BD       16  22.1 2016-08-01 21:00:00       16 23              2.25
```

Comment: Hi Jordo82, Thanks for your time. When I run your code, at the last step (joining df1 and df2), I get this message: "Warning message:
Column `Site` joining factors with different levels, coercing to character vector". The script works but I get a data frame with zero rows and 8 variables. Do you know what could be the problem? I've tried changing either `df1$Site` and `df2$Site` to characters (instead of factors), but I get the same result.

Comment: Additionally, I don't understand your final output otherwise. In your output you don't have the times `16:25:16` nor `20:54:16`, why? Instead of this, you have the times `17:29:16` and `22:48:16` duplicated. I also see that time allocation is wrong. For instance, at the time `17:29:16` corresponds the `Current.Int` of 4.75, since you have to take the row in `df2` corresponding to the time `18:00:00`, and take a look on the column `df2$m32-39` (the depth of the fish is 42 meters and in those cases I want to take the Current value from the deepest layer).

Comment: Another example about allocation: the currents allocation for `df1[6 , ]` corresponds to the time `21:00:00` from `df2`. Since the time of `df1[6 , ]` is `22:48:16`, its closest time from `df2` is `00:00:00` of the next day (`2016-08-01`).

Do you understand my comments? Do you know how to fix them? Thanks in advance for your time. The code is really close to get what I need.