# Create a new categorical variable in df1 that takes into account one df1 variable and several df2 variables with multiple conditions

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse, lubridate

I have a data frame similar to those use in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56190193/create-a-variable-in-df1-depending-on-one-variable-of-df1-df1var1-and-o) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56191446/calculate-the-mean-between-several-columns-of-df2-that-can-vary-according-to-the) post. The reason is because I need to create three different variables in my dataset and I did a different post for each question since the way they are approached differs from one another.

`df1` summarises the depth of different fishes over time at different places. `df2` summarises the intensity of the currents over time (EVERY THREE HOURS) from the surface to 39 meters depth at intervals of 8 meters (`m0-7`, `m8-15`, `m16-23`, `m24-31` and `m32-39`) in a specific place. As an example:

```
df1<-data.frame(Datetime=c("2016-08-01 15:34:07","2016-08-01 16:25:16","2016-08-01 17:29:16","2016-08-01 18:33:16","2016-08-01 20:54:16","2016-08-01 22:48:16"),Site=c("BD","BD","BD","BD","BD","BD"),Ind=c(16,17,19,16,17,16), Depth=c(5.3,24,36.4,42,NA,22.1))
df1$Datetime<-as.POSIXct(df1$Datetime, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",tz="UTC")


> df1
             Datetime Site Ind Depth
1 2016-08-01 15:34:07   BD  16   5.3
2 2016-08-01 16:25:16   BD  17  24.0
3 2016-08-01 17:29:16   BD  19  36.4
4 2016-08-01 18:33:16   BD  16  42.0
5 2016-08-01 20:54:16   BD  17    NA
6 2016-08-01 22:48:16   BD  16  22.1

df2<-data.frame(Datetime=c("2016-08-01 12:00:00","2016-08-01 15:00:00","2016-08-01 18:00:00","2016-08-01 21:00:00","2016-08-02 00:00:00"), Site=c("BD","BD","BD","BD","BD"),var1=c(2.75,4,6.75,2.25,4.3),var2=c(3,4,4.75,3,2.1),var3=c(2.75,4,9.8,2.25,1.4),var4=c(3.25,3,6.5,8.9,3.4),var5=c(3,4,2.3,2.6,1.7))
df2$Datetime<-as.POSIXct(df2$Datetime, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",tz="UTC")
colnames(df2)<-c("Datetime","Site","m0-7","m8-15","m16-23","m24-31","m32-39")

> df2
             Datetime Site m0-7 m8-15 m16-23 m24-31 m32-39
1 2016-08-01 12:00:00   BD 2.75  3.00   2.75   3.25    3.0
2 2016-08-01 15:00:00   BD 4.00  4.00   4.00   3.00    4.0
3 2016-08-01 18:00:00   BD 6.75  4.75   9.80   6.50    2.3
4 2016-08-01 21:00:00   BD 2.25  3.00   2.25   8.90    2.6
5 2016-08-02 00:00:00   BD 4.30  2.10   1.40   3.40    1.7
```

I want to create a new variable in `df1` called `Outside_currents` that reflects if the fish avoids HIGH CURRENTS. I define the column `Outside_currents` as "Tell me if the fish AVOID to be in a layer of high currents when HE HAS A CHANCE TO BE THERE OR NOT". My fishes move ALWAYS at depths biggers than 15 meters, so I only take into account for this calculations the last three columns (`m16-23`, `m24-31` and `m32-39`).

Transformed this into mathematics:

`Outside_currents`: "when one or two layers OUT OF THE THREE CONSIDERED (`m16-23`, `m24-31` and `m32-39`)  have current intensities THREE TIMES GREATER than the other one or two, is the fish OUTSIDE?".

The possible answers would be:

1. `Yes`: the fish is in the layer in which the current intensity is three times LOWER compared to one or two of the other layers.
2. `No`: the fish is in the layer or layers that have a current intensity three times greater than the rest.
3. `NA`: when that condition does not exist (there is no any layer with a current intensity 3 times bigger than in the others), or when the variable depth is "NA".

I would expect this:

```
> df1
             Datetime Site Ind Depth Out_current
1 2016-08-01 15:34:07   BD  16   5.3          NA
2 2016-08-01 16:25:16   BD  17  24.0          NA
3 2016-08-01 17:29:16   BD  19  36.4         YES
4 2016-08-01 18:33:16   BD  16  42.0         YES
5 2016-08-01 19:33:16   BD  17  24.0          NO
6 2016-08-01 20:54:16   BD  16    NA          NA
7 2016-08-01 22:48:16   BD  16  22.1          NA
```

Comment: It seems like 90% of this question is repeating your prior question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56190193/create-a-variable-in-df1-depending-on-one-variable-of-df1-df1var1-and-o  Is there a way you can make your question simpler so we can help you just with the part that hasn't already been addressed, which might be more useful for others.

Comment: Why are rows 3 and 4 `YES`? They do not seem to be three times bigger, but maybe I am looking at the wrong values.

Comment: There is a great deal of overlap between this question, the one I mentioned above, and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56191446/calculate-the-mean-between-several-columns-of-df2-that-can-vary-according-to-the

Comment: Thanks for your comment william3031 and Jon Spring. @JonSpring, this post is different from the others I faced in other posts. I used the same examples because in the 3 cases, I work with the same datasets, but I need to create different variables, all related to currents. One of the posts is to calculate the current intensity at the depth where the fish is, another post is to calculate the mean current where the fish NOT is, and this post is to look at another different question: do the fish avoid high currents? The approach to this question is different, and I don't know how to do it now.

Comment: In fact, here I change a little bit the data frame `df2`. @william3031, you were right... I made a mistake with `df2` and I used the wrong one. I've changed it and now you can see why `df1[3 , ]` and `df1[4 , ]` are `YES`, because at the closest time for these datetimes in `df2` (at `18:00:00`), if we look at only the las three depth layers, we see that in the depth between 32 and 39 meters the current is more than three times lower than in the layers `m16-23` and `m24-31`, and since the fish was at either 36 or 42 meters depth, he chose to be OUTSIDE the currents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution:

```
library(data.table)

library(lubridate)

library(dplyr)

df1<-data.frame(Datetime=c("2016-08-01 12:34:07","2016-08-01 15:34:07","2016-08-01 16:25:16","2016-08-01 17:29:16","2016-08-01 18:33:16","2016-08-01 19:23:16","2016-08-01 20:01:16","2016-08-01 20:54:16","2016-08-01 22:48:16","2016-08-01 23:48:16","2016-08-02 01:07:16"), Site=c("BD","BD","HG","BD","BD","BD","BD","BD","BD","HG","BD"),Ind=c(16,16,17,19,16,16,17,16,16,17,16), Depth=c(15.50,5.30,24.00,36.40,42.00,25.00,NA,22.10,54.00,27.00,21.50))
df1$Datetime<-as.POSIXct(df1$Datetime, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",tz="UTC")
df1$Datetime_rounded<-round_date(df1$Datetime, "3 hour")

df2<-data.frame(Datetime=c("2016-08-01 12:00:00","2016-08-01 15:00:00","2016-08-01 18:00:00","2016-08-01 21:00:00","2016-08-02 00:00:00"), 
            Site=c("BD","BD","BD","BD","BD"),
            var1=c(2.75,4.00,6.75,2.25,4.30),
            var2=c(3.80,7.75,4.75,3.00,2.10),
            var3=c(2.20,4.30,6.80,2.25,3.40),
            var4=c(5.40,1.10,2.25,3.30,6.50),
            var5=c(7.30,5.20,1.30,2.60,1.70))
df2$Datetime<-as.POSIXct(df2$Datetime, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",tz="UTC")
colnames(df2)<-c("Datetime","Site","m0-7","m8-15","m16-23","m24-31","m32-39")

df1<-df1[,c(1,5,2,3,4)] # Rearrange the data frame

setDT(df1) # We convert into data.table
setDT(df2)

setkey(df1, Site, Datetime_rounded) # We indicate the key variables.
setkey(df2, Site, Datetime)

df_merge = df2[df1, roll = -Inf] # Associate one table with the other.
df_merge<-df_merge[,c(8,2,9,10,3:7)] # Rearrange the data.table

df_merge[, Outside_current := case_when(
  Site != "BD" ~ "NA",
  Depth == "NA" ~ "NA",
  Depth < 15 ~ "NA",
  Depth >= 15 & Depth < 24 & (`m16-23`*3 < `m24-31` | `m16-23`*3 < `m32-39` | `m16-23`*3 < (`m24-31`+`m32-39`)/2 ) ~ "Yes",
  Depth >= 24 & Depth < 32 & (`m24-31`*3 < `m16-23` | `m24-31`*3 < `m32-39` | `m24-31`*3 < (`m16-23`+`m32-39`)/2 ) ~ "Yes",
  Depth >= 32 & (`m32-39`*3 < `m16-23` | `m32-39`*3 < `m24-31` | `m32-39`*3 < (`m16-23`+`m24-31`)/2 ) ~ "Yes",
  Depth >= 24 & (`m16-23`*3 < `m24-31` | `m16-23`*3 < `m32-39` | `m16-23`*3 < (`m24-31`+`m32-39`)/2 ) ~ "No",
  (Depth >= 15 & Depth <24 | Depth >= 32) & (`m24-31`*3 < `m16-23` | `m24-31`*3 < `m32-39`  | `m24-31`*3 < (`m16-23`+`m32-39`)/2 ) ~ "No",
  Depth < 32 & (`m32-39`*3 < `m16-23` | `m32-39`*3 < `m24-31` | `m32-39`*3 < (`m16-23`+`m24-31`)/2 ) ~ "No",
  T ~ "NA")]

> df_merge
             i.Datetime Site Ind Depth m0-7 m8-15 m16-23 m24-31 m32-39 Outside_current
 1: 2016-08-01 12:34:07   BD  16  15.5 2.75  3.80   2.20   5.40    7.3             Yes
 2: 2016-08-01 15:34:07   BD  16   5.3 4.00  7.75   4.30   1.10    5.2              NA
 3: 2016-08-01 17:29:16   BD  19  36.4 6.75  4.75   6.80   2.25    1.3             Yes
 4: 2016-08-01 18:33:16   BD  16  42.0 6.75  4.75   6.80   2.25    1.3             Yes
 5: 2016-08-01 19:23:16   BD  16  25.0 6.75  4.75   6.80   2.25    1.3             Yes
 6: 2016-08-01 20:01:16   BD  17    NA 2.25  3.00   2.25   3.30    2.6              NA
 7: 2016-08-01 20:54:16   BD  16  22.1 2.25  3.00   2.25   3.30    2.6              NA
 8: 2016-08-01 22:48:16   BD  16  54.0 4.30  2.10   3.40   6.50    1.7             Yes
 9: 2016-08-02 01:07:16   BD  16  21.5 4.30  2.10   3.40   6.50    1.7              No
10: 2016-08-01 16:25:16   HG  17  24.0   NA    NA     NA     NA     NA              NA
11: 2016-08-01 23:48:16   HG  17  27.0   NA    NA     NA     NA     NA              NA
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I am missing something about your question. It seems you are only looking at df2 and anytime a current flags as 3x higher than at one depth, the current will flag as 3x lower in one of the other depths. I put this together. See if it can help get you started.

```r
library(tidyverse)

outside_calcs <-
  df2 %>% 
  gather(depth, value, m16_23:m32_39) %>% 
  left_join(df2) %>% 
  mutate(
    comp_16 = m16_23/value,
    comp_24 = m24_31/value,
    comp_32 = m32_39/value,
    min_diff = pmin(comp_16, comp_24, comp_32),
    max_diff = pmax(comp_16, comp_24, comp_32)
  ) %>% 
  mutate(
    outside_currents = 
      case_when(
        min_diff < 0.33 ~ "Yes",
        max_diff > 3 ~ "No",
        TRUE ~ NA_character_
      )
  )

#            Datetime Site  depth value m16_23 m24_31 m32_39 comp_16 comp_24 comp_32 min_diff max_diff outside_currents
# 2016-08-18 21:00:00   BD m16_23  2.25   2.25    8.9    2.6   1.000    3.96   1.156    1.000     3.96               No
# 2016-08-18 21:00:00   BD m24_31  8.90   2.25    8.9    2.6   0.253    1.00   0.292    0.253     1.00              Yes
# 2016-08-18 21:00:00   BD m32_39  2.60   2.25    8.9    2.6   0.865    3.42   1.000    0.865     3.42               No
```

```r
final_outside <-
  outside_calcs %>% 
  mutate(depth = str_replace(depth, "m", "c")) %>% 
  select(
    Datetime, Site,
    depth, outside_currents
  ) %>% 
  spread(depth, outside_currents) %>% 
  left_join(df2) %>% 
  select(Datetime, Site, starts_with("m"), starts_with("c"))

final_outside  

#            Datetime Site m16_23 m24_31 m32_39 c16_23 c24_31 c32_39
# 2016-08-18 12:00:00   BD   2.75   3.25    3.0   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
# 2016-08-18 15:00:00   BD   4.00   3.00    4.0   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
# 2016-08-18 18:00:00   BD   9.80   6.50    2.3    Yes   <NA>     No
# 2016-08-18 21:00:00   BD   2.25   8.90    2.6     No    Yes     No
# 2016-08-19 00:00:00   BD   1.40   3.40    1.7   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
```

Comment: Thanks @yake84. My goal is to discover if my fishes avoid or not layers with high currents when they can choose (if they can't choose, the question doesn't have sense). Currents intensity records are reflected in `df2` every 3 hours. What I need is to say in my variable `Outside_currents` if the fish, for at specific `Datetime` and considering its depth, avoids hight currents.

Comment: When none of the last three depth layers has currents 3 times lower than the others, I write `NA` in `Outside_currents`. An example of this is row 2 in `df1`, since according to `df2`, at  `15:00:00` (the closest time to `16:25:16`) there was no any HIGH CURRENT at all.

Comment: An example of the presence of HIGH CURRENTS is row 3 and 4 in `df2`, since in them there is at least one out of three last layers that has a current intensity three times lower than in the others. I don't know if you understand... My desire is to say if the fish is in the layer/s with low current (then we add `YES`) or in the layer/s with high currents (we add `NO`)...